# OutOfMemoryError while writing a file using FileOutputStream

Tags: android, kotlin, out-of-memory, fileoutputstream, file-writing

I'm facing an OutOfMemoryError while writing a file which is not reproducible every time but it's happening frequently for few users and I got below error while checking logs.

```
2023-05-03 12:11:11.257 6986-6986/com.example.dev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.dev, PID: 6986 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 265048 byte allocation with 96648 free bytes and 94KB until OOM, max allowed footprint 201326592, growth limit 201326592 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3260) 
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125) 
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:451) 
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:137) 
at com.TestTracLogger.formatLog(TestTracLogger:97) 
at com.TestTracLogger.writeFile(TestTracLogger:86) 
at com.TestTracLogger.debug(TestTracLogger:64) 
at com.ITestTracLoggerRepresentable$DefaultImpls.debug$default(ITestTracLoggerRepresentable.kt:8) 
at com.TestTracLogger.writeFile(TestTracLogger:90)
```

And this error is occurring to infinite. Below mentioned the code where it's pointing out the problem.

```
    private fun writeFile(tag: String, msg: String, exception: Throwable?) {
    try {
        if (logFileOutputStream != null) {
            logFileOutputStream.write(formatLog(msg).toByteArray())
            logFileOutputStream.flush()
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        debug(TAG, "Error in writing log i.e.($msg) to file " + e.message)
    }
}

private fun formatLog(msg: String): String {
    val dateTime: String =
        DateFormatterUtility.formatDateTimeToString(Date(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    return "$dateTime : $msg \n"
}
```

Comment: `formatLog(msg).toByteArray()` requires twice the memory of `msg` (one time as `String`, the other as `byte[]`). Better to use an `OutputStreamWriter` on the `FileOutputStream` and then directly write `msg` to it. That should apply the encoding on-the-fly while writing and thus does not require that much RAM.

Answer (score 0):

How long is the Stack Trace? - I think you may have have a recursion defect.

If there is an `IOException` then your exception handling calls `debug` method which I think (I cannot see all the code) recurses to call `writeFile` again and if that fails with another `IOException` then it will loop.  Notice that the `msg` grows each time... in the limit this will except your Heap space for growing that space.

Next step in your investigation change

```
debug(TAG, "Error in writing log i.e.($msg) to file " + e.message)
```

to

```
debug(TAG, "Error in writing log: " + e.message)
```

i.e. do NOT include the `msg` then the explosion in `msg` won't happen.  Or consider not logging this using your custom logger.

Comment: Stacktrace is too long and it repeats last 3 lines again and again.

Comment: In which case, you DO have a recursive error as I described.  Try breaking it in the way I describe at the end.

Comment: Yeah I got it, it was happening due to the catch block. I stopped calling it in the catch block and it resolved. Thanks for your effort.